# Connection between diffusion and non-integrable 1D spin chains

Tags: diffusion, integrable-systems, spin-chains

My question concerns non-integrable (à la Bethe) 1D spin chains.

Consider, for example, the 1D non-integrable Ising model

\begin{equation}
H = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}\sigma_{i}^{z} \sigma_{i+1}^{z} + g_x \sigma_i^{x} + g_z \sigma_i^{z}   \hspace{6pt},
\end{equation}

with $g_x,g_z \neq 0$.

Define the energy density $h_i$ as

\begin{equation}
h_i = \sigma_{i}^{z} \sigma_{i+1}^{z} + g_x \sigma_i^{x} + g_z \sigma_i^{z} \hspace{6pt},
\end{equation}

and the correlator (at infinite temperature) as

\begin{equation}
C(x,t) = (h_x,h_0(t)) = (h_x,e^{i \mathcal{L}t}h_0) \hspace{6pt},
\end{equation}

where (.,.) is the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product and $\mathcal{L} = [H,.]$ the Liouvillian.

In the limit $t \to \infty, x\to \infty$, the correlation function is governed by hydrodynamics.
Usually,in this limit, the correlator tends to the heat kernel

\begin{equation}
C(x,t) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 D t}} \hspace{6pt}.
\end{equation}

Are there any rigorous or semi-rigorous arguments that shed light on the connection between non-integrability and diffusion (perhaps involving a random walk on the chain)?

Is superdiffusive transport (e.g. KPZ) possible in non-integrable systems?